# PHP login script T_SL error

Tags: php

I'm making a register page on 000webhost and I save the code, open the site up and I get this error : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL on line 40.

```
<?php 
require('config.php'); 

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{
$email1 = $_POST['email1']; 
$email2 = $_POST['email2']; 
$pass1 = $_POST['pass1']; 
$pass2 = $_POST['pass2']; 

if($email1 == $email2 && $pass1 == $pass2) 
{ 
//All good 
$name = mysql_escape_string($_POST['name']); 
$lname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']); 
$uname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['uname']); 
$email1 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email1']); 
$email2 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email2']); 
$pass1 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass1']); 
$pass2 = mysql_escape_string($_POST['pass2']); 

$pass1 = md5($pass1); 
//Check if username is taken 
$check = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uname = '$uname'")or die(mysql_error()); 
if (mysql_num_rows($check)>=1) echo "Username already taken"; 
//Put everyting in DB 
else{ 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `lname`, `uname`, `email`, `pass`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$lname', '$uname', '$email1', '$pass1')") or die(mysql_error()); 
echo "Registration Successful"; 
} 
} 
else{ 
echo "Sorry, your email's or your passwords do not match. <br />"; 
}



} 
else{ 
$form = <<<EOT 
<form action="register.php" method="POST"> 
First Name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br /> 
Last Name: <input type="text" name="lname" /><br /> 
Username: <input type="text" name="uname" /><br /> 
Email: <input type="text" name="email1" /><br /> 
Confirm Email: <input type="text" name="email2" /><br /> 
Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" /><br /> 
Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2" /><br /> 
<input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit" /> </form> 
EOT; 

echo $form; 

} 

?>
```

I have spent a bit attempting to solve the issue but I cant find the problem.

Comment: I have tried your code on my localhost and it's working fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly on line 40 `$form = <<<EOT`  you cannot have anything after the heredoc name, in your case you have spaces after "EOT"  `$form = <<<EOT[space]`

Comment: Ahhh never realised I had spaces after it Thank you for the help!